# Rename field only on Serialization in java

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, annotations

I have an object named AddOnsSRO.Only on serialization I want the names of fields of the object to be changed.

Tried using @JsonProperty on getter methods but it gives me a renamed field even on usages where serialization is not involved.

```
public class AddOnsSRO {

    private String sideCar;
    private String sideCarCoverage;

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonProperty("abc")
    public String getSideCar() {
        return sideCar;
    }

    public void setSideCar(String sideCar) {
        this.sideCar = sideCar;
    }

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonProperty("xyz")
    public String getSideCarCoverage() {
        return sideCarCoverage;
    }

    public void setSideCarCoverage(String sideCarCoverage) {
        this.sideCarCoverage = sideCarCoverage;
    }
}
```

**Only on serialization** the following fields : `sideCar` and `sideCarCoverage` must be renamed to `abc` and `xyz` respectively.

For any other use except serialization the field names should be `sideCar` and `sideCarCoverage` only.

Please help and suggest changes or annotations accordingly.

Comment: Are you working with jackson library?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan yes

Comment: Maybe you can try [@JsonAlias](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonproperty-and-jsonalias-example)

Comment: @AkinerAlkan where do i use this...please do suggest an updated code for the same

Comment: What you mean by "gives me a renamed field even on usages"? `AddOnsSRO x; x.getSideCar();` doesn't work?

Comment: @talex i meant if the same AddOnsSRO is to be used somewhere else in my code where serialization is not involved then the fields name must be sideCar and sideCarCoverage only.
no, AddOnsSRO x; x.getSideCar(); doesn't work!

Comment: @ankur43 It is extremely unusual. For annotation to change a name of method you should use some compile time annotation processing. I don't know any json lib who use annotation processing. Can you create [mcve]

Comment: jackson version?.. if you are using old ...thn please use latest

Comment: @AkinerAlkan could you please help?

Comment: @ankur43, I agree with user7294900's answer which should work in your scenario. If it does not solved your problem probably you need to take look somewhere else in your code which overrides this functionality.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan no it's not working!

Answer (score 2):

For effecting only serializing use [@JsonGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonGetter.html) instead of `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonGetter("abc")
public String getSideCar() {
    return sideCar;
}
```

> Getter means that when serializing Object instance of class that has this method (possibly inherited from a super class), a call is made through the method, and return value will be serialized as value of the property.

You can add `@JsonSetter` to setter method for deserialize:

```
@JsonSetter("sideCar")
public void setSideCar(String sideCar) {
    this.sideCar = sideCar;
}
```

Comment: @ankur43 add on setter the desrialize value

Comment: @ankur43 added `@JsonSetter` to answer

Answer (score -1):

your code looks good...Please upgrade your jackson lib... if you are using old